# Software needs Core i5-750 2.67 GHz, my PC has Core i7-3610QM 2.30-3.30 GHz; will it work?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, gaming, intel-core-i7, cpu-speed

My mobile computer has the following CPU:

> Intel Core i7-3610QM - 2,30 - 3,30GHz 6MB 45W "Ivy Bridge"

As far as I understand is my computer able to speed up to 3,30 GHz?

I want to <s>play a game</s> run serious simulations and the software requires the following CPU:

> Intel Core i5-750, 2.67 GHz

Will it work? (Other requirements are reached or exceeded.)

Comment: The Intel Core i5-750 is a generation older, though its a desktop. I guess *if* other requirements are met, there's no reason why not.

Comment: The dynamic boost is usually only applied to single/a few cores so if that software is multi-threaded or you're doing multiple things you might not be able to get the full boost. It's probably going to run slower if your CPU isn't lacking any features the software needs.

Comment: The Core-750 is 2 generations older then the CPU you have.  In other words your CPU exceeds the CPU requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i7 is significantly better than the i5, the largest part is probably the generational improvements that have happened. The i7 is a third generation processor while the i5 is first generation and a lot of efficiency improvements have been made.

To compare the processors:

```
                       i7-3610QM        i5-750
CPU Class              Laptop           Desktop
Clockspeed             2.3 GHz          2.7 GHz
Turbo Speed            Up to 3.3 GHz    Up to 3.2 GHz
Max TDP                45W              95W
Single Thread Rating   1634             1136
CPU Mark               7457             3722
```

<sub><sub>(Courtesy of [cpubenchmark.net](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=891&cmp%5B%5D=772))</sub></sub>

The single core performance of the i7 is better by a good margin, but the CPU mark (which would take multicore performance in to account) is significantly better, even considering that the i7 is almost half the thermal rating of the i5.

As long as the rest of your system meets requirements then your processor is well above what they are listing as their minimum.